# Error while using recursion to add Binary Tree Node & print parent/child Nodes on same line?

Tags: java, recursion, printing, binary-tree, nodes

I've been staring at this forever, and neither my tutor nor classmates were able to find what might be happening. Any help at all would be so appreciated!

I have an error in my binary tree program somewhere that is causing for the lefthand leaf to be printed repeatedly and the righthand leaf to be skipped, but I can't figure out where it might be.

The assignment specifies the design and method signatures that we're to use, as well as using recursion in certain methods, so I can't change any of that. Each node has an array of up to two child nodes.

We need to format the printing so that each node is printed on the same line as its children.

For example:

```
    Node rootNode = new Node("A");
    rootNode.addChild("B", "A");
    rootNode.addChild("E", "A");
    rootNode.addChild("F","E");
    rootNode.addChild("H","E");
    rootNode.addChild("C", "B");
    rootNode.addChild("D", "B");
    rootNode.printTree();
```

Should return:

```
    ABE
    BCD
    C
    D
    EFH
    F
    H
```

But is instead printing:

```
    ABE
    BCC 
    C 
    C 
    EFH 
    F
    H
```

Node "D" is missing while "C" is getting reprinted, but somehow Node "H" (also the righthand leaf just like "D", but on the right branch instead of the left) is still getting printed correctly. When I use my find() method on "D" it returns null which seems to indicate it isn't getting put in the tree, so I think the error is in my addChild() method. I just can't for the life of me find where it is.

```
 public boolean addChild(String ID, String parentID) {
        if(myID.equals(parentID)) {  // found parent
            if(children[0] == null) {
                children[0] = new Node(ID, find(parentID));
                numberOfChildren++;
                return true;
            }
            if (children[1] == null) {
                children[1] = new Node(ID, find(parentID));
                numberOfChildren++;
                return true;
            }
            else {
            //  System.out.println("This is already full.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if(numberOfChildren == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else if(numberOfChildren == 1) {
                return children[0].addChild(ID, parentID);
            }
            else { 
                if(children[0].addChild(ID, parentID) == false) { 
                    return children[1].addChild(ID, parentID);
                }
                else {
                    return children[0].addChild(ID, parentID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, the issue might be in the toString/print method:

```
public String toString() {
    String childOne = "";
    String childTwo = "";
    if (children[0] != null) {
        childOne = children[0].getId();
    }
    if(children[1] != null) {
        childTwo = children[1].getId();
    }
    return(myID + childOne + childTwo);
    
}

@Override
public void printTree() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(toString() + " ");
    
    if(children[0] != null) {
        children[0].printTree();
        
    }
    if(children[1] != null) {
        children[1].printTree();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The first step is to use a debugger to determine whether the problem lies in tree construction or tree printing -- i.e., does the tree actually **have** the data that are not printed?

Comment: The issue is in the construction - the Node "D" returns null when trying to call find(), which should return the node. Outside of that, when the debugger gets to addChild("D", "B"), it goes to if(numberOfChildren == 0) then return children[1]/addChild(ID, parentID)